# How to find the manual page of apt install?

Tags: apt

Suppose I want to read the manual page of `sudo apt install -f`.

How to do that ? I mean if I search in `man 8 apt` I get few details about the `install` option of `apt`. Is there a way to check the `-f` option.

Comment: There is `apt` and `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `man apt-get` and there you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: I know, but i want details about the front end `apt`

Comment: `apt-get` is part of `apt` and install, remove etc are documented in `apt-get` section